# Add custom tab on the media manager

Tags: media, file-manager

I want to add a new tab and its content on the media manager. I have used `add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'mime_type_tab' , 1 , 1 );` but that filter it is not working on the featured image pop up.

[image]

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185271/how-to-add-new-tab-to-media-upload-manager-with-custom-set-of-images